# wxpython GUI program to exe using py2exe

Tags: python, user-interface

I am new to python programming and development. After much self study through online tutorials I have been able to make a GUI with wxpython. This GUI interacts with a access database in my computer to load list of teams and employees into the comboboxes.

Now my first question is while converting the whole program into a windows exe file can I also include the .accdb file with it...as in I only need to send the exe file to the users and not the database..if yes how.

My second question is... I actually tried converting the program into exe using the py2exe (excluding the database...am not sure how to do that) and I got the .exe file of my program into the "Dist" folder. But when I double click it to run it a black screen (cmd) appears for less than a second and disappears. Please help me understand the above issue and resolve it.

am not sure if I have a option of attaching files...then I could have attached my wxpython program for reference.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Premanshu

Comment: I expect your executable is printing something to the terminal and then exiting, taking the terminal with it.  Try opening a terminal and running your exe from the terminal?

Comment: Hi, I got the solution for the problem. I simply imported one more module into my program which was missing. I imported decimal module and then converted it into exe and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console could possibly appear if you used the 'console' parameter to setup(). Switch to 'windows' instead if that is the case. Can't say for sure without seeing your setup.py script. Possibly your app could also be opening console, but again hard to say without seeing source. One thing to check is to make sure you are not printing anything to stdout or stderr. You might want to redirect all of stdout and stderr to your log just in case, and do this right at the top of your start script so that if some 3rd party import was writing to stdout you'd be able to capture that.

The db is not part of your executable, so py2exe will not do anything with it. However, you should probably package your application with an installer, and you can make the installer include the db and install it along with the executable.

Comment: Hi Heikki, Thank you very much for looking into the question and trying to help me. Besides I have found the solution which I mentioned above as a comment. I must also explain how I found the answer is...... I tried and captured a screenshot of the black window which was appearing for a fraction of second using the "PrntScrn" key and then got to know what error I was actually getting. Then I searched the net for the solution and found that I need to import the decimal module as well and it worked. Thank you very much again for looking into it. Have a good day :).